# Passing ARG to parent docker stage

Tags: docker, dockerfile

We are writing several small pieces of code that pretty much use the same logic in Dockerfile on different directories.

I would like to achieve something similar

```
ARG image=python:3.7-alpine
FROM $image as python_base
ARG CODE_DIR
ARG API=internal

WORKDIR /orka

# Copy in api files
COPY ./orka_engine_api/orka_api/common.py ./orka_engine/orka_api/
COPY ./orka_engine_api/orka_api/$ARG_API.py ./orka_engine/orka_api/

# Copy in the code
COPY $CODE_DIR ./$CODE_DIR

# make utils and code modules importable
ENV PYTHONPATH $PYTHONPATH:/orka/orka_engine/python_libs/:/orka/$CODE_DIR


FROM python_base as www CODE_DIR=www API=external
RUN apk update && apk add wget && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "-m", "main"]


FROM python_base as worker CODE_DIR=worker
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "-m", "main"]
```

I.e., I would like to be able to speficy *in Dockerfile* build args for parent stage to use. Can I do that?

Comment: you want to overide the value of `ARG image`?

Comment: Up to spelling errors, I'd expect the Dockerfile you posted to work.  Are you having a specific problem with it?